# How to fix ClassNotFoundException, for unity app embedded in android?

Tags: c#, android, android-studio, unity-game-engine

I have embedded unity app with an android app following [Embedded Unity within Android App](https://medium.com/@davidbeloosesky/embedded-unity-within-android-app-7061f4f473a).

I have used two unity plugins [NatCorder - Video Recording API](https://assetstore.unity.com/packages/tools/integration/natcorder-video-recording-api-102645) and [Android Native Pro](https://assetstore.unity.com/packages/tools/integration/android-native-pro-125691) plugin in my unity project.

This is for Unity 2018.3.8f and Android studio 3.1. I am getting `AndroidJavaException: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException:` for both of my library files.

Log:

```
09-05 11:46:00.587 22881-22925/com.example.mitesh.myapplication E/Unity: AndroidJavaException: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.stansassets.core.utility.AN_ImageWrapper
    java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.stansassets.core.utility.AN_ImageWrapper
        at java.lang.Class.classForName(Native Method)
        at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:400)
        at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:326)
        at com.unity3d.player.UnityPlayer.nativeRender(Native Method)
        at com.unity3d.player.UnityPlayer.c(Unknown Source)
        at com.unity3d.player.UnityPlayer$e$2.queueIdle(Unknown Source)
        at android.os.MessageQueue.next(MessageQueue.java:392)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:142)
        at com.unity3d.player.UnityPlayer$e.run(Unknown Source)
     Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.stansassets.core.utility.AN_ImageWrapper" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.example.mitesh.myapplication-1/base.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.example.mitesh.myapplication-1/split_lib_dependencies_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.example.mitesh.myapplication-1/split_lib_slice_0_apk.apk", 
09-05 11:46:00.605 22881-22925/com.example.mitesh.myapplication E/Unity: AndroidJavaException: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.stansassets.core.utility.AN_Logger
    java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.stansassets.core.utility.AN_Logger
        at java.lang.Class.classForName(Native Method)
        at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:400)
        at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:326)
        at com.unity3d.player.UnityPlayer.nativeRender(Native Method)
        at com.unity3d.player.UnityPlayer.c(Unknown Source)
        at com.unity3d.player.UnityPlayer$e$2.queueIdle(Unknown Source)
        at android.os.MessageQueue.next(MessageQueue.java:392)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:142)
        at com.unity3d.player.UnityPlayer$e.run(Unknown Source)
     Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.stansassets.core.utility.AN_Logger" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.example.mitesh.myapplication-1/base.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.example.mitesh.myapplication-1/split_lib_dependencies_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.example.mitesh.myapplication-1/split_lib_slice_0_apk.apk", zip file "/data/apk

09-05 11:47:42.810 23384-23423/com.example.mitesh.myapplication E/Unity: AndroidJavaException: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.stansassets.core.utility.AN_UnityBridge
    java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.stansassets.core.utility.AN_UnityBridge
        at java.lang.Class.classForName(Native Method)
        at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:400)
        at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:326)
        at com.unity3d.player.UnityPlayer.nativeRender(Native Method)
        at com.unity3d.player.UnityPlayer.c(Unknown Source)
        at com.unity3d.player.UnityPlayer$e$2.queueIdle(Unknown Source)
        at android.os.MessageQueue.next(MessageQueue.java:392)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:142)
        at com.unity3d.player.UnityPlayer$e.run(Unknown Source)
     Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.stansassets.core.utility.AN_UnityBridge" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.example.mitesh.myapplication-1/base.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.example.mitesh.myapplication-1/split_lib_dependencies_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.example.mitesh.myapplication-1/split_lib_slice_0_apk.apk", zip

09-05 11:46:57.671 22881-22925/com.example.mitesh.myapplication E/Unity: AndroidJavaException: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.yusufolokoba.natcorder.MP4Recorder
    java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.yusufolokoba.natcorder.MP4Recorder
        at java.lang.Class.classForName(Native Method)
        at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:400)
        at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:326)
        at com.unity3d.player.UnityPlayer.nativeRender(Native Method)
        at com.unity3d.player.UnityPlayer.c(Unknown Source)
        at com.unity3d.player.UnityPlayer$e$2.queueIdle(Unknown Source)
        at android.os.MessageQueue.next(MessageQueue.java:392)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:142)
        at com.unity3d.player.UnityPlayer$e.run(Unknown Source)
     Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.yusufolokoba.natcorder.MP4Recorder" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.example.mitesh.myapplication-1/base.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.example.mitesh.myapplication-1/split_lib_dependencies_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.example.mitesh.myapplication-1/split_lib_slice_0_apk.apk", zip file "/data/ap
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not possible because those plugins were made for Unity and not to use as a plugin for android.